# Clear image cache from Grid background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, caching

Hopefully I can explain what I need and what the problem is

I have the followings list box

```
    <ListBox Margin="0,8,0,0"  toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" x:Name="ImageList" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  BorderThickness="4">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="{Binding imageID, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Width="125" Height="125" Margin="6" Tap="list_OnTap">

                    <TextBlock Name="description" Foreground="{Binding TextColor}" Text="{Binding text}" Visibility="{Binding ShowText, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False" Name="deletectx">
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete"  Click="delete_Click"/>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

The above code makes a grid of images, I used Grid background to show the image because I needed to show my text on the image (Not sure if there is any other way to do this)
This page load about 30 images with the size 125x125 pixel and about 4kb each. I noticed that it consumes a lot of memory. I read some posts here about clearing the cache of the images, but I don't know how I'm supposed to do that with the above code considering I'm setting a grid background as my image not an image control.

I might be able to access the grid inside the listbox, but whatever I do with it, will be applied to the first image only not the rest. I need to clear the images cache on my navigate away event.

Another question , I also have some performance problem , entering this page takes a little bit of time and I get low frame rate warning in Windows Phone App Analyser, not sure if what I'm doing (loading images through Converter for each listbox item) is right or not ! 
How can I make this faster ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When choosing a title for your question, there's no need to include tags in them. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190 for the discussion and why they're not needed. Also, greetings at the end is unnecessary, include any greetings in your contact card instead, it's displayed in the bottom right of all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that you can reclaim any memory used by the default image caching behaviour you can use to following: (snipped from another project and edited slightly but should work as is.)

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        // Unload all images so as to reclaim any allocated memory
        foreach (var child in VisualTreeHelperEx.GetVisualChildren(this.ImageList).Where(c => c is Image))
        {
            var image = child as Image;

            if (image != null)
            {
                var bitmapImage = image.Source as BitmapImage;

                if (bitmapImage != null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("unloading " + bitmapImage.UriSource);
                    bitmapImage.UriSource = null;
                }

                image.Source = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which uses this helper:

```
public static class VisualTreeHelperEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetVisualChildren(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }

        return GetVisualChildrenAndSelfIterator(element).Skip(1);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetVisualChildrenAndSelfIterator(DependencyObject element)
    {
        Debug.Assert(element != null, "element should not be null!");

        yield return element;

        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
        }
    }
}
```

This may have it's own performance issues so use with care and test the impact on actual performance.

The performance problem on page load is probably due to all the images being loaded at once. You could drip feed them into the list after the page has loaded to avoid this. If the actual images are larger than the background area you should set the `DecodePixelHeight` and `DecodePixelWidth`. It may also be worth removing the converter and adding a property with the full path as lots of complex converters can impact performance.